# How to add a dataframe to a mysql table using RODBC

Tags: mysql, r, dataset, addition, deducer

An absolute beginner at R so please excuse any obvious questions.

I am trying to update a MySQL table ('exdata3' in database' test') with the dataframe from Deducer.

I had initially called the database and used the table in deducer, run some queries on it which is stored in the dataframe 'data1'. Now I want to send 'data1' which contains a new column and update the non-empty table in MySQL, exdata3.

(In future I might not have new columns/rows but the existing columns might have different values  in the dataframe as compared to the same columns in MySQL, if you know what I mean )

The difference between the dataframe and the table in MySQL is the addition of a column 'DiffHighLow' (which contains the values calculated from two other coulmns in the table) in the dataframe.

I am using RODBC to communicate between R and MySQL on 64 bit Windows7

I have tried the following with the subsequent errors.

**1. > sqlSave(channel, data1, exdata3, append= TRUE,rownames = "DiffHighLow", colnames = TRUE, verbose = FALSE, safer = TRUE, addPK = FALSE, "integer", fast = TRUE, test = FALSE, nastring = NULL)**

Error in sqlSave(channel, data1, exdata3, append = TRUE, rownames = "DiffHighLow",  : 
  object 'exdata3' not found

**2.> sqlSave(channel, data1, rownames = "DiffHighLow", addPK = TRUE)**

Error in sqlSave(channel, data1, rownames = "DiffHighLow", addPK = TRUE) : 
  42S21 1060 [MySQL][ODBC 5.3(w) Driver][mysqld-5.0.41-community-nt]Duplicate column name 'diffhighlow'

[RODBC] ERROR: Could not SQLExecDirect 'CREATE TABLE `data1`  (`DiffHighLow` varchar(255) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, `exdata3_id` integer, `date` double, `open` double, `high` double, `low` double, `close` double, `shares_` integer, `turnover_` double, `diffhighlow` double)'

**3rd. > sqlUpdate(channel,data1, "exdata3")**

Error in sqlUpdate(channel, data1, "exdata3") : 
  data frame column(s) date open high low close shares_ turnover_ diffhighlow not in database table

I don't understand, amongst other things, why its not recognizing the row names which already exist in the database table except for 'DiffHighLow'

Please advise. I have searched for such a question on SO a lot and tried the the various solutions already posted (that looked most alike to my query)but none of them seem to be working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you load the contents of a table, `exdata3` into R from a MySQL database, modify it by among other things adding a new column, `DiffHighLow`, and now you want to save it back to the MySQL database. If that is what you are trying to do, this will work:

```
# this just sets up the example
set.seed(1)    # for reproducible example
df <- data.frame(Open=rnorm(50), Low=rnorm(50), High=rnorm(50), Close=rnorm(50))
library(RODBC)
channel <- odbcConnect(dsn="MySQL", case="nochange")
sqlSave(channel,df,"exdata3", rownames=F)

data1 <- sqlQuery(channel,"select * from exdata3")
data1 <- transform(data1,DiffHighLow=High-Low)

# you start here
sqlQuery(channel,"drop table exdata3")
sqlSave(channel,data1,"exdata3")
result <- sqlQuery(channel,"select * from exdata3")
head(result)
```

The basic problem is that `sqlSave(...)` requires *either* that the MySQL table not exist at all (in which case it will be created), *or* that it has columns which map exactly to the columns in your database. You can't add columns using `sqlSave(...)`. So this code simply deletes the original version of `exdata3` and then creates a new copy from the data in `data1`. The last line just reads the table back in to demonstrate that it worked.

There are a couple of problems with your code.

The first try fails because you pass a variable name `exdata3`, instead of a character string `"exdata3"`. You don't have a variable named `exdata3` in your R environment, hence the error: "object 'exdata3' not found".

The second try fails because you are telling the ODBC driver to save the data frame's row names in a column called `diffhighlow`, but there is already a column in `data1` with that name, so the driver is trying to create two columns with the same name.

The third try fails because the columns in `exdata3` don't map out to the columns in `data1`.

Comment: Thanks so much for your detailed explanation. Yes that's exactly what Im trying to do. I had to try it a few times and solve minor errors before finally getting it right.